# How to prevent admin superusers from causing "Site matching query does not exist" errors?

Tags: python, django, high-availability

There are many SO questions about the Django errormessage `Site matching query does not exist.`:

- [Site matching query does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814059/site-matching-query-does-not-exist)
- [Django - Site matching query does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068518/django-site-matching-query-does-not-exist)
- [Getting Site Matching Query Does Not Exist Error after creating django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476210/getting-site-matching-query-does-not-exist-error-after-creating-django-admin)
- [Django project /admin Site matching query does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505981/django-project-admin-site-matching-query-does-not-exist)
- [Django admin DoesNotExist at /admin/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736975/django-admin-doesnotexist-at-admin)
- [Django CMS malfunction: Site matching query does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674615/django-cms-malfunction-site-matching-query-does-not-exist)
- [Admin login stopped functioning Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957360/admin-login-stopped-functioning-django)

In all these cases, the cause was correctly identified to be the absence of a row in the `django_site` table with the id specified as `SITE_ID` in `settings.py`.

Well, I want to prevent this from happening in the future. Right now, I have given a select few administrators superuser access to the Django admin. They have the power to destroy all data, if they want, and they are responsible for it. I myself, however, am responsible for server availability and want to prevent any Server 500 errors. In the current situation, my staff superusers can delete objects from the `django_site` thereby rendering the site inaccessible, which I find unacceptable.

How can I prevent admin superusers from rendering the complete website inaccessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom admin class like so:

```
class DeleteNotAllowedModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Other stuff here
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

If you only want to prevent deletion of say the last site and allow when there are more than one defined in the database:

```
class DeleteNotAllowedModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Other stuff here
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if Site.objects.count() > 1:
            return True
        return False
```

Or something like this.

Edit: and as for how to register that custom class, look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects)